# Proper OAuth flow using Azure AD to authenticate a internal, single-tenant mobile app

Tags: android, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

My company has an internal web app and several other services that use Azure AD for authentication. Because they are SPA and single-tenant, they are able to use implicit grant flow in order to avoid the use of access and refresh tokens.

I am building an internal mobile app that needs to use Azure AD for auth and should also be single-tenant(my org). My understanding is that this is insecure for mobile applications. The only flows I see that apply to mobile include using access tokens to gain access to Microsoft protected API's. I understand that I am able to expose my internally hosted API but that doesn't seem to be allowed in Azure AD with a single-tenant configuration. Therefore I cannot request API access as a scope and the whole system of access and refresh token breaks down.

In addition, all of the client libraries I see are setup for the access token and not sending raw ID tokens or refreshing them. Is something like firebase on top on my app a solution? I have been all over the microsoft docs on this and am struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that I am able to expose my internally hosted API but that doesn't seem to be allowed in Azure AD with a single-tenant configuration.

This is incorrect. You *can* use Azure AD to secure access to your API even when used by a single-tenant client app.

You can create an app registration for your backend API (where you would define at least one scope), and a separate app registration for you client app (which would request the scope defined for your backend API).

If the client app and backend are really all one logical app, you could also define a since app registration, define at least one scope for it, and the client app would request that scope.

In both cases, the client app ends up with an access token to the backend API, and can use that for API requests.

I *strongly* recommend not implementing the flows directly. Use an SDK that will handle all the token juggling. The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for iOS and Android is available for production use now and really makes this fairly trivial: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/microsoft-authentication-libraries-for-android-ios-and-macos-are-now-generally-available/

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to separate out the API as you suggested and create a scope. The next issue is that because this is an on-premises API, it appears in order to protect it, I need to create an API Gateway through an Azure resource called API management and do some DNS and certifcate config where I guess the gateway acts like a proxy?

Comment: I would add that I hope there is another way to achieve this because the API gateway approach seems fairly complex for our use case.

Comment: You might want to ask that in a separate question (though careful about staying [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here on StackOverflow, since library recommendations are not on-topic). (You may also want to take a look at [Secure access to on-premises APIs with Azure AD Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-secure-api-access).)